# Non-reponsive site, not formatting properly on mobile and tablet

Tags: mobile-safari

I can't seem to figure out why this site is not defaulting to display full screen on mobile devices and tablets (I'm only looking on iphone and kindle fire). It is also left aligning on the screen, rather than centering. The site is not yet responsive, so I'm not using any media queries.

http://dev.dhmsounds.com/

The homepage also shows the full image for the promotional banner when I have:

```
html,body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
max-width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:#534f4b;
color:#534f4b;
z-index:-500;
border:0;

 }

 body{overflow-x: hidden;}
```

The site works fine in Firefox, Chrome and Safari web browsers (still testing in IE).

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried a fixed width?

Comment: actually, if I change to:
    max-width:922px;
The site displays on web browsers the way it is displaying on the phone.

Comment: actually, I'm gonna go through the css a little bit more... I"m seeing a few things in IE as well.. once I fix that, maybe it'll fix the mobile layout.

Comment: Ok, I fixed a few things on IE, but that didn't solve my mobile/tablet problem. The site is still left-aligned and not displaying at 100%. Any ideas?

I've tried putting a min-width, max-width on the html,body as well as a pixel dimension rather than percentage... nothing seems to help. It almost seems like the whole site is zooming out, because the brown footer should extend all the way to the bottom as well.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem if anyone is running into the same situation. I had a width:100% on my ul in my footer. That solved the issue for all the inner pages, however for the homepage, I also had to ad an overflow-x:hidden on my main promotional banner eventhough it was already applied to the body.